# Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. admin.py

Tags: python, django

im trying to override queryset in admin.py to return a queryset based on each user's group, for a model Transaction
`models.py`

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
....
   income_period_choices = (('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Fortnightly',
                                                'Fortnightly'))
   chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                 choices=income_period_choices,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True, default='Weekly')
   property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                           max_digits=7,
                                           decimal_places=2,
                                           null=True,
                                           blank=True)
```

`admin.py`

```
@admin.register(Transaction)
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['chp_reference', 'familymember__name']
   inlines = [FamilyGroupInline, FamilyMemberInline]

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       obj.user = request.user
       print(obj.user)
       super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

   def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super().get_queryset(request)
       if request.user.is_superuser:
           return qs
       return qs.filter(user__groups__first=request.user.groups.first())
```

im getting the error for the last line filter query, is there any suggestions? would be so much appreciated

Comment: Your transaction model does not seem tho have a `user = ...` field.

Comment: yes, im depending on the built in user model that comes with django. do you mean i must add a `user = ..` field ?

Comment: yes a `ForeignKey` from your `Transaction` to the user model.

Comment: now im getting an error: `Related Field got invalid lookup: first`

Comment: @AbdullahOsama: well there is no such thing as a "first" group. In a database data is "unordered". So that means the first group can each time be something different.

Comment: so im trying to return a qs for each group, so that only users at each groupd can acces their own data. what is the best approach to do that?

Comment: `return qs.filter(user__groups__user=request.user)`. This means that if they have  group in common, then you can see the `Transaction`s. If each user thus belongs to only one group, then you only see the transactions for people in the same group. If a user can be a member of more groups, it is sufficient to have one group in common.

Comment: thank you so much, its working this way

Comment: one more question, what is best approach to make the transaction based on group not user, so if a user in a specific group and made a transaction, and in future this user moved to another group. i want the transaction stay still in the group. how should it be done

Comment: you make a `ForeignKey` to the `Group` model instead.

Comment: and sorry, then it should be like ` return qs.filter(groups__user=request.user)` ?